# Reste Animated gif on refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animated-gif

So I recently used this piece of code so the animated gifs can work again after refreshing a page and it's working fine in chrome, safari, internet explorer EXCEPT firefox, I need help please

jQuery:

```
$(img).css("background-image","url('../images/rt2/728x90_Animated_bg_2x.gif"+"?a="+Math.random()+"')");
```

Comment: What is the expected outcome? Do you get any errors on the console?

Comment: Ahhh I came across this, this is the same fix I applied, it seems once an animated gif is loaded in FF next refresh only the last gif slide is shown as static. No worries this is the best fix I could find :)

Comment: @yvesmancera the outcome is the gif image disappears in firefox

Comment: @joyBlanks even if I refresh the page the gif image isn't there, this is what my problem is, thanks

Comment: can you upload/attach the image. Maybe the last frame of the gif might be transparent. Is it 'looping forever gif' or one time loop??

Comment: also could you show your HTML is the variable img is a div or an img tag??

Comment: @joyBlanks it's a one time loop and it's an div tag, I don't know why this is happening only on firefox, thanks again

Comment: give a try with `<img>` tag and a random number everytime. Check if you can fit a img tag in your app. Hope it works else there is no other way as of now. FF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be do to Bug 129986 - "Cached Gif animations don't reset on reload". You can check out more information here: 
http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap141202.html

The nasa.gov website seems to have the same issue with firefox at least:
http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap141202.html

The gif will work about 4 times and then stops. Refreshing the page (`F5`) does not fix the problem. However, it will work if you manually refresh the cache (`CRTL + F5`).

I tested the below code with firefox and the gif always keeps playing.

```
var img = new Image();
src = '../images/rt2/728x90_Animated_bg_2x.gif';
img.src=src;

setInterval(function(){
    t=new Date().getTime();
    $("img").attr("src", src+'?'+t);
},5000);
```

*Edit*:

I tried the way you had it originally and ran into the same trouble (img was not showing). The below worked for me in Firefox.

```
var img = new Image();
src = '../images/rt2/728x90_Animated_bg_2x.gif' + '?a=' + Math.random();
img.src=src;
$('img').css('background-image',"url("+img.src+")");
```

Comment: I guess what Luis is facing is she is not seeing the image. Yes the hack worked for me but lets see if her image has some mystery to tell.

Comment: @joyBlanks I'm not seeing the image only in firefox, every other browser works, and I'm a he, lol

Comment: @LuisQ , Glad it worked for you! Would you mind accepting this as the answer since it solved the issue?